# What does the "-1" mean on an injured soldier after a battle?

Tags: expeditions-conquistador

Occasionally, when a soldier was incapacitated in battle, a -1 will show on their portrait in the after battle screen. What does this number mean?

My first guess was that it meant they lost -1 equipment, since I saw somewhere that you can lose equipment when you are incapacitated. However, I checked my number of equipment and I'm fairly sure that it did not change from the battle.